# If statement/Outlook/VBA : Drafting Emails

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, outlook

The purpose of this code is to make an email draft to users who submitted a reclass. The MailTo and Subject are pulled from an excel data table: `ecEmailAdresses = 17` and `ecSubject = 43` . The line it which I need help on is the `**`If Statement`**`. I want the macro to only draft up an email if the person submitted a reclass (this is also a section on the excel table: labeled Reclass and each cell either has a Y for yes and N for no). How would I go about this? Thank you.

Also, the code below keeps repeating itself and makes way more drafts than I need.

```
 Option Explicit
    'Enumeration is by definition the action of establishing the number of something
    'I Enumerated my Worksheet Columns to give them a meaningful name that is easy to recognize so if the amount is ever moved

    Public Enum EmailColumn
        ecEmailAdresses = 17
        ecSubject = 43
    End Enum
    Public Sub SaveEmails()

    Dim r As Long
    Dim ReCol As Range

    For Each ReCol In Worksheets("Report").Range("AP1:AP1047900").Cells
    If ReCol = "Y" Then

        'The With Statement allows the user to "Perform a series of statements on a specified object without specifying the name of the object multiple times"
        '.Cells(.Row.Count, ecEmailAdresses).End(xlUp).Row actually refers to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data insert").Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses).End(xlUp).Row
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
            '.Cells(): references a cell or range of cells on Worksheets("Data insert")
            '.Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses): References the last cell in column 43 of the worsheet
            '.End(xlUp): Changes the reference from the last cell to the first used cell above the last cell in column 17
            '.Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdressess).End(xlUp).Row: returns the Row number of the last cell column 17
            For r = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses).End(xlUp).Row
                getTemplate(MailTo:=.Cells(r, ecEmailAdresses), Subject:=.Cells(r, ecSubject)).Save
            Next
        End With
     End If
     Next ReCol

    End Sub
    Public Function getPOAccrualTemplate(MailTo As String, Optional CC As String, Optional BC As String, Optional Subject As String) As Object
        Const TEMPLATE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\Project\ Email Template.oft"

        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        'CreateObject("Outlook.Application"): Creates an instance of an Outlook Application.
        'Outlook.Application.CreatItemFromTemplate returns a new MailItem Based on a saved email Template
        Set OutMail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItemFromTemplate(TEMPLATE_PATH)

        With OutMail
            .To = MailTo
            .CC = CC
            .BCC = BC
            .Subject = Subject
        End With

        'Returns the new MailItem to the caller of the function
        Set getTemplate = OutMail

    End Function
```

Comment: I bet you don't really need to loop through `1047900` rows.

Comment: Why don't you filter first by the Reclass column="Y" and then process the Visible cells range `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`? Also - Add `Option Explicit` to top of module and then make sure it compiles first, to fix obvious coding errors like the one pointed out in answer below

Comment: @dbmitch: Interestingly, `Option Explicit` is already included in the code sample!

Comment: @AJD - good point - something is amiss

Comment: @FinanceGuy. You do realise that the string you redacted is still visible in the edit review list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems.

`Public Function getPOAccrualTemplate(MailTo As String, Optional CC As String, Optional BC As String, Optional Subject As String) As Object`
which includes `Set getTemplate = OutMail`. Should be (notwithstanding other inefficient coding practices):

```
Public Function getPOAccrualTemplate(MailTo As String, Optional CC As String, Optional BC As String, Optional Subject As String) As Object
    Const TEMPLATE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\Project\PO Accrual Push Back Email Template.oft"
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutMail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItemFromTemplate(TEMPLATE_PATH)
    With OutMail
        .To = MailTo
        .CC = CC
        .BCC = BC
        .Subject = Subject
    End With
    Set getPOAccrualTemplate= OutMail
End Function
```

Your loop in `SaveEmails` is doing exactly what you are asking it to, creating the multiple templates. Each time you have a "Y" you then loop through all the rows and create an e-mail, effectively squaring the number of emails needed. If I understand your logic and your datasheet correctly, removing the loop should solve the repetition problem (Notwithstanding other inefficient coding).

```
   If ReCol = "Y" Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
                getTemplate(MailTo:=.Cells(Recol.Row, ecEmailAdresses), Subject:=.Cells(Recol.Row, ecSubject)).Save
        End With
     End If
```

Comment: Couple things: (1) What are you trying to explain to  me in the first part of you answer? (2) What are you meaning when you state "(Notwithstanding other inefficient coding)" ? (3) Where would I implement the If Statement you provided. Thank you

Comment: Also, how do I establish the range for ReCol? It will change every month, that's why the range for the email address and email subject us Long.

Comment: (1) Look at the VBA syntax help to see how you return information from functions. This is fundamental for how the language works. Sites such as MSDN provide the technical reference. (2) Your code has other problems not directly related to the question and I don't have time at the moment to work through them all.  (3) I provided an alternative `If` statement for the one you already have, so implement it where you have implemented your current version. (4) Your code already establishes the range for `Recol`, why are you asking me how you establish the range for `Recol`?

Comment: Your code shouldn't even run the way it's posted in the question. You're calling `getTemplate`, yet your function is called `getPOAccrualTemplate`. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module, compile it til you have no errors, then repost your code in an edit to your question.

Comment: @AJD I got confused by your answer and I thought my whole approach was wrong on selecting the range in which the if statement would be applied too.

Comment: @dbmitch I forgot to remove some things on my end. I edited the initial question so its consistent. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Just a some clarification I am a novice when it comes to VBA. So if you could edit you answer to my question on visually implementing the code into my macro that would help me greatly!

Comment: @FinanceGuy: You would get more value by looking at your code, seeing where my code is similar to yours, and making the edits yourself. The changes are relatively small and it would help you create better code in the future.

Comment: @AJD ok that makes sense. The reason why I asked if it was possible to visualize the implementation of the code is because when I removed the loop I received an run-time error on the `getTemplate(MailTo:=.Cells(r, ecEmailAdresses), Subject:=.Cells(r, ecSubject)).Save`line stating the "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: That will be because `r` is defined in the loop. You will see that the row is defined by your outer loop (`Recol` is the cell/range on the row that you want) and my code used `Recol.Row`.